# Bad Request Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand

Tags: magento2, api, curl

I am trying to make get an oauth acces token from magento but when i sent the data i receive this error.

`Bad Request Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand`

This is the header of the request im sending.

`"Authorization":"OAuth oauth_consumer_key=\"blank for privacy reasons\", oauth_callback=\"blank for privacy reasons\", oauth_nonce=\"2hf5FfiJplHLFBslkDbJBX4xnebUUTZw\", oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\", oauth_timestamp=\"1667573144\", oauth_version=\"1.0\", oauth_signature=\"PJPiRYAIZG2cnkBTmfMuexzw%2BGc%3D\"","Accept-Encoding":"deflate, gzip","Accept":"*\/*","Content-Length":"0","Host":"magento-control-panel.test","Content-Type":""}`

the request goes to `/oauth/token/request`. I sent the data using Curl.

```
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            'Authorization: ' . $data["Authorization"],
            'Content-type: ' . $data["Content-type"],
            'Host: ' . $data["Host"]          
        ),
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);

    curl_close($curl);
    echo $response;
```

I dont know what i did wrong. If you know a way to fix it please let me know, Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the issue. When i comment `Content-type` and `Host` in the `HTTPHEADER` the request goes through. I think the request might be too big with those parameters included. hope this helps someone!!!